# Extract values in a string separated by commas

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

1. I want to extract the values separated by commas in the string. I am able to do that but how can i also get rid of the space padded at the beginning of each value starting from second value.
   I know i can just remove the space in the input, but the plan is to get input from the user and so i want to make sure the extra spaces are removed and just the values are extracted.

   ```
   import java.util.Arrays;
   public class HelloWorld{
   public static void main(String []args){
   System.out.println("Hello World");
   String input = "";
   String[] result = input.split(",");
   for(String a : result)
       System.out.println(a);
   Arrays.sort(result);
   for(String a : result)
       System.out.println(a);

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: What is your question? Or is this "Do my homework"?

Comment: In regards to get rid of extra spaces. There is a function called [`trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) that is available for strings.

Comment: What have you tried so far for solving **question 2**? Please first try it by yourself and then call back with some code and a specific problem where you stuck. An idea would be to just iterate the array and do a matching task. Get an element and check whether the next element is the correct follower, if yes, remember it and so on. For this you probably need to extract the number, you can do this with **regex** or other stuff that is able to parse numbers out of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the `String#trim` method ([Java-Doc of String#trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--)) on each element which cuts all **whitespace character** at the beginning and end of a `String`.

Here is a snippet fitting your example:

```
String[] result = input.split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    // Fetch the item, trim it and put it back in
    result[i] = result[i].trim();
}
```

Or you could change the splitting delimiter as the correct delimiter seems to be `,[whitespace]` and not just `,`. The code would then be:

```
String[] result = input.split(", ");
```